# Difference between behavioral and dataflow in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have searched to understand what is the difference between behavioral and data flow code in `verilog`. at last i can't find good example for that, everywhere tell the thing that they do.
for example :

"Its very simple.Name itself explains what they are.Dataflow is one way of describing the program.Like describing the logical funtion of a particular design.
Behavioral model on the other hand describes the behavior of the system.How does it behave when particular input is given?"

[here](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-behavioral-and-data-flow-in-Verilog) is written very simple example but I need more examples.

Comment: The more common term for "dataflow modelling" is "RTL". Anyway google "RTL vs behavioral" will help you more than you will get here.

Comment: Related cross-site dupe: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63682/difference-between-rtl-and-behavioral-verilog

Answer (score 7):

Dataflow modeling in Verilog allows a digital system to be designed in terms of it's function. Dataflow modeling utilizes Boolean equations, and uses a number of operators that can acton inputs to produce outputs operators like + - && & ! ~ || | << >> {}
so if i want to describe a 2 to 4 decoder in dataflow modeling i would be like this

```
module decoder2to4 ( e , a, b, do, dl, d2, d3);
input e, a, b;
output do, dl, d2, d3;
assign dO = ( e & ~a & ~b); //00
assign dl = (e & ~a & b);   //01
assign d2 = (e & a & ~b);   //10
assign d3 = ( e & a & b);   //11
endmodu1e
```

on the other hand The Behavioral modeling in Verilog is used to describe the function of a design in an algorithmic manner
so if i want to describe a 2 to 4 decoder in dataflow modeling i would be like this

```
module decoder2to4 (e, i, d);
output [3:0] d;
input [l:0]i;
input e;
reg [3:0] d;
    always @ (i or e) begin
            if (e==l) begin
                case (i)
                       0: d = 4'b 0001;
                       1: d = 4'b 0010;
                       2: d = 4'b 0100;
                       3: d = 4'b 1000;
                      default d = 4'b xxxx;
               endcase
            end
            else
               d = 4'b0000;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: so if we want to write something with 1000 bit in behavioral modeling, how should we do that? 1000 case? @ahmed salah

Comment: behavioral modeling isn't about using the case block it's about describing the behavior of the system without  thinking of the actual circuit formed while synthesis

Comment: ok,in your example you want to describe the behave of circuit with different inputs so you use case. in your example how do you write your code if it was decoder 16 to 2^16? @ahmedsalah

Comment: i can write 2^16 line to describe that behave but that would take a lot of time instead i would declare  a 2d array which get it's values form a text file using the function $readmemb and the input would be the address of the array  and the output would be like this  d=array[I] the text file can be written by any software language like matlab, python or perl

Answer (score -1):

Dataflow modeling works based on continuous assignment and behavioral is based on process-based implementation.

*continuous assignment*

```
assign d=a||b;
```

*behavioral assignment*

```
always@(a,b)
begin
d=a||b;
end
```

This is a small example of my idea.

Comment: You should cite a reference for your claim.  I don't see any mention of the term "dataflow" (or anything like it) in the IEEE Std (1364 or 1800).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).